# Does the teleportal in Kingdom Rush have an official name? Can it be activated?

Tags: kingdom-rush, kingdom-rush-frontiers

In either Kingdom Rush or Kingdom Rush: Frontiers there is a circular object that looks as though it might be a teleportal. Sadly clicking on it shows that it is broken - only some of its lights come on.

I am trying to find a good-quality image of it but am not sure what search term to use.

Does it have a name? Can it be activated?

Comment: Regular kingdom Rush has portals in its later levels that demons come out of (Pandaemonium, Rotten Forest, Pit of Fire), probably not what you want though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's a TV show reference**

I believe I have found what you are referring to. You can find this in the second level of the second game (Kingdom Rush Frontiers), called [Sandhawk Hamlet](https://kingdomrushtd.fandom.com/wiki/Sandhawk_Hamlet).

The screenshot below is a zoom-in of that part of the level.

[image: Sandhawk Stargate]

This object is a reference to the sci-fi show *[Stargate SG-1](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118480/)*. It does not serve any gameplay purpose like many of the other easter eggs in the game.

Some of these other easter eggs can unlock achievements for finding and activating them.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I've never actually watched Stargate.